# how to make multi inline-block element width stretch 100%

Tags: css

Is there any way to make multi inline-blocks element width stretch to 100% ?

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <select>
    <option>area code</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" style="width:20%">
  -
  <input type="text" style="width:20%">
  -
  <input type="text" style="width:20%">
</div>
```

Comment: not able to understand exactly what you are asking, can you please explain your problem

Comment: you have mentioned width 20% for your inline elements. I am not able to understand your problem. Can you please share a jsfiddle.net

Comment: I think an image of the expected result would help us understand your problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can - but note that `inline-block` element have a little extra unwanted spaced between them like invisible margin which could be removed using different techniques as shown by Chris on **[this page](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)**. I like to use "Remove the spaces" Technique.

I wrapped hyphen "-" in a div so that we can assign him percentage width as well.

Also the input fields were assigned `box-sizing: border-box;` so that its padding is part of it's width.

**[Here is the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/vE2aF/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <select>
        <option>area code</option>
    </select
    ><input type="text" 
    /><div class="sperator">-</div
    ><input type="text" 
    /><div class="sperator">-</div
    ><input type="text" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap > *{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24%;
}
.wrap > *.sperator{
    width: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}
input {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this: **[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/WM99F/)**

**CSS:**

```
.form {
    width:100%;
}
.controls {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
    margin:0 5px;
}
.controls select, .controls input {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Since there are 4 elements inside form the width should be 25% but that wont work in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/WM99F/1/) cuz of the line-block space issue.

Answer (score 1):

## css

```
#f1 {
    width:100%;
    font-size:0;
}
.controls {
    display:inline-block;
    width:23%;
    margin:0 2% 0 0;
}
.controls select, .controls input {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #ccc;

}
```

## Html

```
 <div id="f1">
    <div class="controls">
        <select>
            <option>area code</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text"  />
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text"  />
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

## it take 100% width